# How to update a shell namespace extension without explorer restart?

Tags: windows, shell, explorer, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

I have a [shell namespace extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095(v=vs.85).aspx), using [a file system folder as its junction point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file) (by creating a desktop.ini file with my extension's CLSID in the folder).

When upgrading to a new version of the extension, I would like to avoid restarting all processes that have the extension loaded (which is the suggested answer in [How to unload C++ Shell Extension DLL properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365944/how-to-unload-c-shell-extension-dll-properly)), to provide a better user experience.

I've tried:

- [SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [SHFlushSFCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which was suggested in [Reload a namespace extension in explorer.exe that failed to load previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596688/reload-a-namespace-extension-in-explorer-exe-that-failed-to-load-previously)
- [SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762199(v=vs.85).aspx) with FCS_FORCEWRITE, as suggested in http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/6r9JXG8r/explorer-in-vista-does-not-react-to-a-change-of-clsid-in-desktop-ini

None of the above succeed in forcing explorer to load the new version of the extension.

I also tried registering a completely new CLSID for the new version of the extension and removing the registration for the old one. This ***mostly*** works, except when opening any previously existing **shortcuts** pointing to the folder. In that case, neither the old nor new extension are loaded, and the default shell folder is used to display the folder. I again tried SHChangeNotify, SHFlushSFCache, and SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings, and none of them fixed this issue with shortcuts.

I tested this on Windows 7 and Windows 10 Fall Creators.

Comment: Note NSE can be loaded by any process that opens a file dialog (notepad, word, you name it), so it's kind of impossible to do it right anyway. At least Explorer supports the restart API so it doesn't loose its state/windows, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes I realize that, all the more reason that I think there should be some way to get the shell to load a new version of the extension, regardless of the host process.

Comment: You can't unload a dll from a process you don't own. The only way would be to implement your NSE as a proxy and write the real NSE as an out-of-process server, talking to the proxy.

Comment: @SimonMourier, it's ok if the old dll stays loaded, as long as the new dll is the one that is used when browsing into the file system folder junction point. That was what I was going for when trying out using a new CLSID for the new dll's shell folder.